# RabbitMQ: What does the 'direct' heading under `rabbitmqctl list_exchanges` mean?

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

If I create an exchange in rabbitmq using php's amqp class with exchange type set to `direct` and the only option specified is `durable`, then try to connect to that exchange in node.js, I get a `Cannot redeclare exchange with different options error` you see if you're options don't match.

However, as far as i can tell, i am using the exact same options (type direct, and option durable). So i did a test and created one exchange in php called `php_exchange` and one in node.js called `node_exchange` and ran `rabbitmqctl list_exchanges` and got some interesting output:

```
Listing exchanges ...
node_exchange   direct
amq.headers headers
amq.direct  direct
amq.match   headers
amq.fanout  fanout
    direct
php_exchange    direct
amq.topic   topic
...done.
```

What does the `direct` heading mean in this context (clearly it's not all exchanges of type direct, as it lists node_exchange as being of type direct)? How can i get node.js to create an identical amqp exchange (so that it won't fail when connecting to a durable exchange)?

I am using the PECL php amqp library and the node-amqp library (https://github.com/ry/node-amqp)

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is the output of `rabbitmqctl list_exchanges name type auto_delete internal arguments` (with the other exchanges removed for brevity):

```
Listing exchanges ...
node_exchange   direct  false   false   []
php_exchange    direct  false   false   []
...done.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a heading - it's a consequence of a slightly confusing aspect of AMQP, which is that there's a direct exchange called "". This is the "default" exchange, to which all queues automatically get bound.

In terms of your problem with PECL vs node-amqp, I don't use either of those, but maybe your exchanges differ in something other than type or durability. "rabbitmqctl list_exchanges name type auto_delete internal arguments" will add more columns to the table returned to show all the details of your exchanges. Or look at the management plugin.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I edited to the original to include the command you mentioned. Are there other possible differences that the management plugin would point out? thanks.